# How to launch an activity that is json and php in fragment of eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I want to put an json, php based activity in each fragment of swip view and I couldn't do it. I put 3 activity on the fragment...

**TabsPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new Activity3();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new Activity1();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            //return new Activity2();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }}
}
```

**Avtivity3.java**

```
public class Activity3 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }}
```

**InsertDataActivity.java**

```
public class InsertDataActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etName,etTel,etMajor;

    Button btnInsert;

    private static  RadioGroup radio_g;

    private static  RadioButton radio_b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etTel=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTel);
        etMajor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMajor);
        radio_g = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.gStatus);
        btnInsert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
        btnInsert.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int selected_id = radio_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radio_b = (RadioButton)findViewById(selected_id);

        InsertData task1=new InsertData();
        task1.execute(new String[]{"http://192.168.137.1:8081/norton2/insert.php"});
        Intent in=new Intent(this, ReadDataActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
        ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(InsertDataActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Sending Data...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            for(String url1:urls){
                try {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtName", etName.getText().toString()));
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtTel", etTel.getText().toString()));
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtMajor", etMajor.getText().toString()));
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtStatus", radio_b.getText().toString()));
                    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url1);
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                    HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertDataActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertDataActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result==true) {
                Toast.makeText(InsertDataActivity.this, "Insert Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(InsertDataActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }}
```

So, I want to put InsertDataActivity.java in Activity3.java how can I insert the activity into the fragment ...any help???